# get the local repo synced with remote

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to sync a local project to an existing remote repo.

from my local folder

```
git init
git remote add origin 
git fetch
```

The thing is that the remote has diverged so it's 2 or 3 commits ahead

I ran

```
git status
```

and got

```
On branch master
No commits yet
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

I need to sync the local with the remote.
If i run

```
git pull origin master
```

I'll get an error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge. Please commit yout changes or stash them.
I won't be able to stash because I don't have an initial commit.

How do I track the files and do a pull request to get the local repo synced with remote?

**Update**
This was solved by running

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/masater
```

Comment: Why do you run `git add .` and then not commit? Why do you want to add all local files to your history?

Comment: ok my bad! let me edit that. I have the local files but I need to sync them with my remote.

Comment: Your best bet is probably just to save your existing files elsewhere, run `git checkout main` or `git checkout master` or whatever, and then move your existing files back into place.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

- First stash the local changes `git stash`
- Then do a pull of the repo `git pull origin master`
- Then pop the stash `git stash pop`
- Then stage the changes using `git add .`
- Then commit and push to master

Comment: I won't be able to stash because I dont have an initial commit in the local repo.

Comment: The error states that there are some local changes made to files that are in the remote. So the stash is done to store the changes locally and then after the pull of the repo is done, the stash is poped and conflicts are resolved.

Comment: There are some local changes because I had the project downloaded then I intialized a repo `git init` and connected it to the remote. so those are the projects file which are identical to the remote. They are untracked and that's why I need to sync the local with remote

Comment: If both remote and local are similar, you could use `git clone repo-url` to get the repo with all the commits.

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/masater
```

Comment: Note that `reset --hard` will "undo" any uncommitted changes you might have in your directory. Any work not committed _will be lost_!